# laravel saving a row to database, and get row and pivot back

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have a model that is setup like this,

```
class Project extends Eloquent {
    public function projectmanager(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'project_manager');
    }
}
```

I run an edit on a row in my projects database, and the project_manager column returns the ID of the user who is project manager, where I as want the user details for that ID - I am saving my data like this,

```
$project = Project::where('id', '=', $id)->get();  
$project->name = Input::get('name');   
$project->description = Input::get('description');    
$project->total_cost = Input::get('cost');   
$project->start_date = Input::get('start_date');   
$project->finish_date= Input::get('finish_date');   
$project->run_number_days = $this->get_days_between_two_dates(Input::get('start_date'), Input::get('finish_date'));   
$project->num_days_from_year_start = $this->get_days_between_two_dates("2014-01-01", Input::get('start_date'));  
$project->project_manager = Input::get('project_manager');  

    $project->save();  

    return $project
```

;

Instead of returning what I have actually saved, how can I return the row, plus all its relationship data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically load your related models

```
$project->save(); 
$project->load('projectmanager');
return $project;
```